# What does an array with a * mean?

Tags: php

I tried searching for this, but see below:

```
Array
(
[*response] => Array
    (
        [body] =>
```

What does it mean if `response` has an asterisk before it?

Comment: In 1 minute I will be able to do so :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe that means it is a **protected variable**.

> If an object is converted to an array, the result is an array whose elements are the object's properties. The keys are the member variable names, with a few notable exceptions: integer properties are unaccessible; private variables have the class name prepended to the variable name; **protected variables have a '*' prepended to the variable name. These prepended values have null bytes on either side.**

[(Source)](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.casting)

Answer (score 0):

If an object is converted to an array, the result is an array whose elements are the object's properties. The keys are the member variable names, with a few notable exceptions: integer properties are unaccessible; private variables have the class name prepended to the variable name; protected variables have a '*' prepended to the variable name. These prepended values have null bytes on either side.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.casting